# cupsd service high memory usage

Tags: printing

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with cups installed for printing. I'm observing that the cups service is gradually increasing memory and reaches 100% in few hours of time.

Could someone help me to find what the actual reason could be for this high memory usage ?

Version informâtion :

apt-cache policy cups
cups:
  Installed: 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.9
  Candidate: 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.9
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.3-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Answer (score 1):

We are running 16.04 server on many machines and had trouble with cups version 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.9 where memory usage would go through the roof and cups web interface and other functions would stop responding. Version 0.8 worked fine. We rolled them back to the latest security release, version 0.6, and that solved the problem.

Now we have a new problem though. Version 0.10 has been released and it is a security release and our machines are set to install all security releases automatically. Version 0.10 contains the bug also and now they cannot be reverted to the previous security release because it is no longer available.

Any ideas on what might be broken in these two versions that worked ok before? Is there another way to roll back to an older version?

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't an answer but might be helpful. Issuing 'lpstat -W completed -u' seems to trigger the CUPS memory leak for me. Until I issue the lpstat command, cupsd looks OK using top.  I can print and release with no issues but if I use lpstat, cupsd is off to the races using memory...Eventually the system becomes unstable.

Answer (score 0):

There's not too much information in your question. Try updating to a more recent version, the Github is at 2.2.11 and Ubuntu disco repos are at 2.2.10. If that doesn't work perhaps make an issue at https://github.com/apple/cups/issues.